# solr search return different results

Tags: search, solr

there is a string field myField with type of lowercase

```
<fieldType name="lowercase" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
      <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" />
      </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

- `q=(MyField:["" TO *])` returns 210470 docs
- `q=(MyField:[* TO *])`  returns 210730 docs

could anyone explain what is the difference between above two queries?
how do I query out those 210730-210470=260 docs? tried `q=(MyField:[* TO *]) AND (-MyField:["" TO *])` which returns 0 doc.

Thanks

edit:
femtoRgon's query worked to find the those 260 docs. After checking I noticed that all the value of MyField in those docs start with "!" (such as "!abc", "!dfd" etc). I still not sure why the MyField:[" TO *] doesn't match those docs?

Comment: Solr can have trouble with negative queries in parentheses like you have there.  Have you tried: `q=MyField:[* TO *] -MyField:["" TO *]`?

Comment: @femtoRgon, thank you. Yes this works. Seems negative queries should be always in the top query and it doesn't work in sub-queries?